# Slicing the first row of a Dataframe into an Array[String]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.{array_apply, array_update}
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object SimpleApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleApp").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = "file:///home/shahid/Desktop/sample1.csv"
    val hdfsOutput = "hdfs://localhost:9001/output.csv"
    val localOutput = "file:///home/shahid/Desktop/output"
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load(input)
    var colLen = df.columns.length
    val df1 = df.filter(!(col("_c1") === ""))
```

> I am capturing the top row into a val named headerArr.

```
    val headerArr = df1.head
```

> I wanted this val to be Array[String].

```
    println("class = "+headerArr.getClass)
```

> What can I do to either typecast this headerArr into an Array[String] or get this top row directly into an Array[String].

```
    val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://localhost:9001"), sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    fs.delete(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/output.csv"),true)
    df1.write.csv(hdfsOutput)
    val fileTemp = new File("/home/shahid/Desktop/output/")
    if (fileTemp.exists)
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(fileTemp)
    df1.write.csv(localOutput)
    sc.stop()
    }
}
```

> I have tried using `df1.first` also but both return the same type.
>
> The result of the above code on the console is as follows :-

```
class = class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
```

> Help needed.
>   Thankyou for you time. xD

Comment: @zork please help

Comment: sample input dataframe and expected Array[String] shall get you quick and exact solution

Answer (score 1):

Given the following dataframe:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("a", "hello"), ("b", "world"))).toDF("id", "word")
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id| word|
+---+-----+
|  a|hello|
|  b|world|
+---+-----+
```

You can get the first row as you already mentioned and then turn this result into a `Seq`, which is actually backed by a subtype of `Array` and that you can then "cast" to an array without copying:

```
// returns: WrappedArray(a, hello)
df.first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Array[_]]
```

Casting is usually not a good practice in a language with very good static typing as Scala, so you'd probably want to stick to the `Seq` unless you really have a need for an `Array`.

Notice that thus far we always ended up not with an array of strings but with an array of objects, since the `Row` object in Spark has to accommodate for various types. If you want to get to a collection of strings you can iterate the fields and extract the strings:

```
// returns: Vector(a, hello)
for (i <- 0 until df.first.length) yield df.first.getString(i)
```

This of course will cause a `ClassCastException` if the `Row` contains non-strings. Depending on your needs, you may also want to consider using a `Try` to silently drop non-strings within the `for`-comprehension:

```
import scala.util.Try

// same return type as before
// non-string members will be filtered out of the end result
for {
  i <- 0 until df.first.length
  field <- Try(df.first.getString(i)).toOption
} yield field
```

Until now we returned an `IndexedSeq`, which is suitable for efficient random access (i.e. has constant access time to any item in the collection) and in particular a `Vector`. Again, you may really need to return an `Array`. To return an `Array[String]` you may want to call `toArray` on the `Vector`, which unfortunately copies the whole thing.

You can skip this step and directly output an `Array[String]` by explicitly using `flatMap` instead of relying on the `for`-comprehension and using `collection.breakOut`:

```
// returns: Array[String] -- silently keeping strings only
0.until(df.first.length).
  flatMap(i => Try(df.first.getString(i)).toOption)(collection.breakOut)
```

To learn more about builders and `collection.breakOut` you may want to have a read [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution @stefanobaghino :- 

I changed my code a little bit to try out your first code :-

`import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray`

and

`val headerArr = df1.first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Array[_]]`

where I get an Error ->

`[error] (run-main-0) scala.MatchError: WrappedArray(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)`

What might be the cause of the Error ?

Comment: It looks like somewhere you are doing pattern matching on your collection and it expects something which is not a `WrappedArray`.

Comment: Did you mean :-  `val headerArr = 0.until(df1.first.length).flatMap(i => Try(df1.first.getString(i)).toOption)(collection.breakOut)`

Comment: Yes, that would be how you apply my solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you have a single column, whose values are strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174705/discussion-between-divine-and-stefanobaghino).

Answer (score 1):

well my problem didn't solve with the best way but i tried a way out :-

```
    val headerArr = df1.first
    var headerArray = new Array[String](colLen)
    for(i <- 0 until colLen){
        headerArray(i)=headerArr(i).toString
    }
```

> But still I am open for new suggestions.
>   Although I am slicing the dataframe into a var of **class = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema** and then transfering the elements to Array[String] with an iteration.